# HTML comments break down

Tags: html, xml, comments, sgml

I have a page that is generated which inserts an HTML comment near the top of the page.  Inside the comment is a *nix-style command.

```
<!-- command --option value --option2 value2 --option3 -->
```

This comment breaks the page completely.  What is wrong with the comment to cause this to happen, and why is this the case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Comments in the [XML Spec from the w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments) :

> For compatibility, the string "--"
>   (double-hyphen) MUST NOT occur within
>   comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to keep the comment in your page you could use this instead of an HTML comment:

```
<div style="display:none">command --option value --option2 value2 --option3 </div>
```

Or even

```
<div class="comment">command --option value --option2 value2 --option3 </div>
```

and specify:

```
.comment {display:none;}
```

in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Comments at the top of the page before `<html>` will throw IE into quirks mode, which could explain why the page breaks, if that's where your comment appears.

For more information, check out the "Triggering different rendering modes" on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)